# como no perder el enfoque gridview android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

```
 <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:columnWidth="70dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/my_awesome_background"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"/>
```

**Ese es mi grid view  con el list selector**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- Selected -->
<item  android:drawable="@drawable/edit_border_image" />
```

**Lo que me pasa es lo siguiente, pierdo el enfoque del grid view que seleccione. Una vez que hago click sobre un grid view queda  seleccionado pero despues de tocar sobre el edit text pierdo el enfoque y se deselecciona. En el ejemplo que muestro se ve como cuando selecciona sobre el grid view queda seleccionada y cuando apreta sobre el edit text se deselecciona.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]